# How to assign row_number to new column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, oracle12c, row-number

My table looks like

```
yr     num   name
2010    1     a
2010    2     b
2011    3     c
2011    1     a
2011    2     b
```

I have to generate sequence for this table and it should look like below

```
yr     num   name   seq
2010    1     a      1
2011    1     a      2
2010    2     b      1
2011    2     b      2
2011    3     c      1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the process for getting the results you describe?

Comment: I tried generating a normal sequence and i want to create trigger for this and im struck in middle

Comment: That is not a normal sequence, you need to compute the column using analytic function. See my answer.

Comment: you should a bit clarify what seq is in the Question text (order of same `name,num` or both at once records/entries?) because right now it is a bit misleading in review reopen process (or it is just me?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate your desired sequence using analytic **ROW_NUMBER** function.

For example,

Let's say your **existing table** looks like:

```
    SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

            YR        NUM N
    ---------- ---------- -
          2010          1 a
          2010          2 b
          2011          3 c
          2011          1 a
          2011          2 b

    SQL>

I generate the desired output using **ROW_NUMBER** and name it `seq`:

SQL> SELECT t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by yr, name) seq FROM t;

        YR        NUM N        SEQ
---------- ---------- - ----------
      2010          1 a          1
      2011          1 a          2
      2010          2 b          1
      2011          2 b          2
      2011          3 c          1

SQL>
```

Now, I create a new table using the above query:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t_new AS SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY yr, NAME) seq FROM t;

Table created.

SQL>
```

So, I have the **new table** with the **desired sequence column**:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t_new;

        YR        NUM N        SEQ
---------- ---------- - ----------
      2010          1 a          1
      2011          1 a          2
      2010          2 b          1
      2011          2 b          2
      2011          3 c          1

SQL>
```

You don't need the **old table**, so **drop it and rename the new table** back to old table:

```
SQL> DROP TABLE t PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL> ALTER TABLE t_new RENAME TO t;

Table altered.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

        YR        NUM N        SEQ
---------- ---------- - ----------
      2010          1 a          1
      2011          1 a          2
      2010          2 b          1
      2011          2 b          2
      2011          3 c          1

SQL>
```

Done!

**NOTE** :

With the **CTAS** approach, please make sure you create the necessary indexes and other things which were associated with the old table.